# Can a property's value be set according to another property of the same element?

Tags: html, css

I want to set the `padding-bottom` property of an element like this:

`padding-bottom: 100% - height;`

where `height` is the height of the object which I'm going to set it's `padding-bottom`.
I'm not changing the `height` and it will be automatically set according to the contents of my element.

For example given the properties of element `elemID`:

```css
#elemID {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #111;
}
```

How can I set it's `padding-bottom` according to it's `height` and more generally how can I access "the value" of other properties of an element in CSS.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155261/how-to-refer-a-css-property-value-from-another-element) but it's not what I want as in my case the value of `height` can't be predicted and I don't want to use variables but properties. I know that this problem can be solved in JS but I want to know if there is a way to solve it in CSS?

Comment: What do you really want to do?  In other words, why do you want to set the padding of one element to the height of another?   Perhaps it can be done a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, sadly, is no. The cascading style sheet language offers no way to reference properties on elements. [Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) are the best native CSS work-around, but you already said that won't do. JavaScript will be the best and easiest way to get a "dynamic" reference to height.

Here's a reference to a similar question asked where the answer kind of addresses yours. The solution was to use [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) and have a list of potential `height`s that could fit, however that doesn't really answer your question. I thought I'd leave it for reference, though:

[Creating or referencing variables dynamically in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass)

Comment: Thank you @lua_python_java . It seems like there isn't any way in CSS and the best option is to run JS onload to change the style that way.